# Moment isValid method keeps returning deprecation warning

Tags: javascript, momentjs

My code is supposed to, given a "value" variable, show either this value formatted in the following date format "DD/MM/YY - HH:mm:ss" (if value is a valid datetime), or just show value itself (if value isn't a valid datetime).

To do that, I'm using the isValid() method from moment.js. I use this method to check if value is a valid datetime and then show the expected result.

My problem is that Moment keeps returning this Deprecation warning when value assumes a non-valid date form.

Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
Arguments:
[0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false, _l: undefined, _i:  , _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]

Does anyone know how I can avoid this warning?

Here's my code:

```
let value = "300";
// sometimes value will be "2020-01-15T11:13:20.960429-03:00", for example - which is a valid date

console.log(
  moment(value).isValid() ? moment(value).format("DD/MM/YY - HH:mm:ss") : value
);
```

Link to codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-resonance-tu68c?file=/src/index.js

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`moment(String, String, Boolean)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) specifying the accepted format using moment tokens (`YYYY`: 4 digit year, `MM`: month, `DD`: days of the month, `HH`: 0-23 hours, `mm`: 0-50 seconds, `ss`: 0-59 seconds, `SSSSSS`: fractional seconds, `Z`: UTC offset) and [strict mode](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/strict-mode/).

Example:

```js
let value = "300";
// sometimes value will be "2020-01-15T11:13:20.960429-03:00", for example - which is a valid date

console.log(
  moment(value, "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ", true).isValid() ? moment(value).format("DD/MM/YY - HH:mm:ss") : value
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```